# Why is nil > 0 true in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Erlang is the first language I come across to give true for nil > 0.

What is the story behind this decision?

Other languages seem to behave differently.

Python:

```
None > 0
# False
```

JavaScript:

```
null > 0
// false
```

Ruby:

```
nil > 0
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: It's part of the [term comparison order](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html): `number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < map < nil < list < bit string`. I'm curious to know why `nil` is so high in the chain as well.

Comment: nil, if used in an expression is an atom: `5 < million < nil < zero < {nil}`, I guess that the `nil` you found in the term comparison paragraph of the Erlang documentation represents an empty list, So it is the smaller possible list, and thus it is at the right place in this order definition. In Erlang, a comparison never fails, and always gives consistent results, it is interesting when you sort a list of heterogeneous terms. IMHO we could spend endless hours to decide if it is true that an atom is always smaller than a pid :o)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Erlang, Any term may be compared with any other term.
The ordering for Erlang Term Comparisons is:

```
number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < map < nil < list < bit string
```

thus **nil > 0** is **true** more information on [Term Comparisons](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81088)

Comment: Using this ordering, I expect nil > reference to yield true.

    A = make_ref().  
    % #Ref<0.0.2.272>
    nil > A.
    % false

Is there something wrong with the code i tried in Eshell?

Comment: In the ordering above, `nil` actually stands for the empty list, `[]`, while if you write `nil` in Erlang code, it is an atom. As per the ordering, any atom is "less" than any reference, so therefore `nil > make_ref()` evaluates to `false`. On the other hand, `[] > make_ref()` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Yes, we were lisp hackers from way back which is why we called the empty list `[]` for `nil` even though in erlang they are completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in Erlang, `nil > 0` evaluates to true. But when Erlang programmer talks about "nil", he means the empty list: `[]`. If you write `nil` in Erlang code, it's just an atom `'nil'`, like `'dog'` or `'hello'`. And any atom is larger than any number because of the following built-in hierarchy:

```
number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < map < nil < list < bit string
```

But it's very important to note that "nil" in this line refers to empty list `[]`, not to the atom `'nil'`.

As a side note: Evaluating `[] > 0` also returns true because any number is smaller than nil.

And finally, `[] > nil` also returns true because nil (`[]`) is larger than any atom (`'nil'`).